# Setting up a vector within a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am looking to set up a application which has for example 10 rows and within each row will be 10 spaces which are split up into various sizes.

With the information that I have been given I have been told that the best approach is to set up a vector within a vector.

Honestly I have an okay knowledge of vectors but I am really unsure on how to put a vector into another.

Could anyone provide me with an example of how to do this?

The best example I found while attempting to research this was -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> stories;
    stories.push_back({"Once", "upon", "a", "time"});

    for (const auto& x : stories)
        for (const std::string& str : x)
            std::cout << str << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

However I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Regards

Comment: So for one `vector`, you write `std::vector<SomeType>`. `SomeType` can be more-or-less anything. So fill in the blanks. What would you write from `SomeType` to be a `vector` of something else? (Note that for older compilers you might need a space between the 2 closing `>`s.)

Comment: A fixed number of items inside of each row sounds more like a `vector<tuple<T, ...>>`.  If `T` is large, keep the `copy` and `move` semantics in-mind when  working with `vector`s and other STL containers.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `vector<vector<int>>`. What this means is a vector of a type which consists of vectors of type `int`. Note that the type `int` here can be 
changed into any other type. I have used it here for representation purposes.

As mentioned in the comments, you use `vector<type>`, where `type` can be anything. So it has been replaced by `vector<int>` in the above example.

Note that before C++11, you need a space between the two angle brackets.

Comment: So I could basically have vector of rows with spaces within it?
'vector<vector <int> spaces >   _rows;'

Would it be possible to have two different vectors in different classes as point them to each other for example if I have a row class and a spaces class. 

And did something similar to the following `std::vector<Row> _rows;`

Comment: @PapaSmurf: What do you mean spaces between it? By space I meant `vector<vector<int> >`, lest you misunderstood. The wording of your comment otherwise is confusing. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry I meant another vector with 10 spaces in but these spaces would have to accommodate sizes for example small box would be 2, medium 4, larges 6 etc.

Comment: @PapaSmurf: If by these variables sizes you are implying strings of different lengths, `vector<vector<string>>` should work fine. There will be no issue. C++ will automatically handle the variable lengths of the strings. All you have to do is push the strings in the `vector<string>` and push this vector into `vector<vector<string>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the syntax is as mentioned: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;`.

> *"However I'm not sure this is the best approach."*

That depends on your actual use cases. As long you know you have a fixed size of 10 rows and columns in your application

```
std::array<std::array<int,10>,10> matrix;
```

may serve you better than the `std::vector<>` approach.